# Is there available differential impedance calculation for this stripline configuration?

Tags: pcb, usb, differential, impedance-matching, trace

I am trying to calculate the differential impedance of a differential pair in a 4-layer PCB as follows:

1. Layer: Low speed signal
2. Layer: Power plane
3. Layer: Differential pair
4. Layer: Ground plane

I am currently using Saturn PCB Toolkit, may I know which settings should I consider:

1. Edge Cpld Ext (Microstrip)
2. Edge Cpld Int Sym (Edge-Coupled Symmetrical Stripline)
3. Edge Cpld Int Asym (Edge-Coupled Asymmetrical Stripline)
4. Edge Cpld Embed
5. Broad Cpld Shld
6. Broad Cpld NShld

Thank you.

SF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only high speed signals are on layer 3 then you choose stripline.  There is no need stated for an asymetric layer space.

Here is a web tool.

[image]
https://www.eeweb.com/tools/symmetric-stripline-impedance
[image]
https://www.eeweb.com/tools/edge-coupled-stripline-impedance
https://www.eeweb.com/tools/edge-coupled-microstrip-impedance
https://www.eeweb.com/tools/broadside-coupled-stripline-impedance

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your answer. Before I confirm on the correct answer, I would like to highlight my question that a stripline doesn't has to be between 2 ground planes right? Like my design, it can be between a power plane and a ground plane. Am I right?

Comment: right. decoupling caps are intended to be <0.1 Ohm in the frequency range of strip lines.

Comment: alright, thanks. May I know why do you relate it to a decoupling caps? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: ac short circuit model equiv planes